# Mocking socket.recv()

Tags: python, sockets, mocking

I want to mock the recv function of a socket and having trouble. Getting errors that I need to actually connect my socket even though I should not have to.

Here is all relevant code:

```
Class A:
    def __init__.py(self):
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    def connect(self):
        self.s.connect((host,port))
    def data_collection(self, d):
        self.send_over_socket(self.cg.get_privilege_command())
        self.send_over_socket(self.status_string)          
        buf = ""
        while 1:
            buf = buf + self.s.recv(self.BUFFER_SIZE).decode()
            #Removed string manipulation below
            self.publish(data from string manipulation)

    def send_over_socket(self,data):
        return (self.s.send(bytes(data.encode())))
```

Pytest code;

```
def test_data_collection():
with mock.patch('moduleA.classA.send_over_socket') as mock_send_over_socket:
    A = classA()
    A.send_over_socket.return_value = 1
    with mock.patch('socket.socket') as mock_socket:
        mock_socket.return_value.recv.decode.return_value = "packet_string"
        with mock.patch('moduleA.ClassA.publish') as mock_publish:
            d = {}
            A.data_collection(d)
            A.publish.assert_called_with("0","500","2","1")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `return_value` for your `mock_socket`; you need to work off of what `socket.socket` is going to return. Your test should look like this:

```
def test_data_collection():
    with mock.patch('socket.socket') as mock_socket:
        A = classA()
        mock_socket.return_value.recv.decode.return_value = "ABC123"
        buf = A.data_collection()
        assert "ABC123" == buf
```

Note that I had to fix some syntax errors in your class code, and I made `data_collection` return the `buf` variable so that it can be tested.

EDIT: File with class:

```
"""receiver.py"""
import socket

IP = 'localhost'
PORT = 80


class classA:
    def __init__(self):
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    def connect(self):
        self.s.connect((IP, PORT))
    def data_collection(self):
        buf = self.s.recv.decode()
        return buf
```

Comment: This did not work as well. The code above is just sorta pseudo code so it is easier to read what my issue is. Right now, my issue is that the mock socket is not 'hooking up' with the socket in my code. when I run pytest, it doesn't know what to do the socket.recv because the socket is 'not connected' to any host/port. So somehow I need to get it to realize that I want the mock socket to be the socket in the code.

Comment: Ok, well given the pseudo code you provided, I changed it to working python. The test I provided does all the proper mocking and does pass. Please provide the actual code you're using.

Comment: I edited my original post at the bottom. Essentially I am not connecting the port ever, I figured with mocking it, I could get away with just returning what I want but perhaps you have to mock the connection as well?

Comment: @Krixen You're correct. The `connect` should be unnecessary if `self.s` is actually a mock object. That all looks fine as well. I'll post my full corrected class. Again, I'd encourage to post your actual code since the code I have here which is a working version of your pseudo-code (including the updated one you just posted) works with the test I posted.

Comment: I just added the actual code, thanks for all the help so far!

Comment: @Krixen The edit was proposed as an edit to my post. Please put the edit on your original question. Also, Please just include the whole file for your whole class. Feel free to get rid of the pseudo code and pseudo code edit you've posted. Just include the actual code and your question/problem.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, I have edited the original post now.

Comment: Not sure if you're still around but I haven't been able to solve this yet. any ideas?

Comment: @Krixen I still can't make it fail like you have. I'm not sure what's different, but the code you've posted still won't run on its own without significant changes. I'm not sure I'll be much help.